# Nautilus / Files does not use icon theme

Tags: unity, nautilus, themes, icons

I just installed a new icon theme on my laptop (ubuntu 13.04). Unfortunately, nautilus/files (version 3.6.3) keeps showing the wrong folder icons (from the Humanity-Theme). As far as I can tell, every other icon is correctly displayed (even folder shortcuts in the dash).

I already restarted the system and copied the icon theme from `~/.icons` to `/usr/share/icons` - without any effects. Since the icon theme works 100% perfectly on my desktop machine, I can tell for sure, that the theme is not broken.

Any ideas?